# How to add font in font.css for using fonts in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to add fonts dynamically in ckeditor. For that i am using config.contentsCss="". Its executing statically. I don't know how to add css in external file or there is another way of adding @font-face to ckeditor.
My code is like this:

```
var fontStyle = '';
        $.ajax({
            url : "/chrysofin/fonts/getFonts",
            success : function(response) {

                $.each(response, function(index, item ) {
                    var fontName = item.name;
                    var eotFile = item.eotPath;
                    var ttfFile = item.ttfPath;

                    fontStyle +=  "@font-face {\n" +
                                        "\tfont-family: \ "+ fontName+"\;\n" + 
                                        "\tsrc:  url('../invitations/fonts/"+ eotFile +"');\n" + 
                                        "\tsrc:  url('../invitations/fonts/"+ ttfFile +"') format('truetype');\n" + 
                                    "}\n" ;

                });
                alert(fontStyle);
                /*CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = function(config) {
                    config.contentsCss = fontStyle;
                };*/
//              CKEDITOR.addCss(fontStyle);

                $.each(response, function(index, item ) {
                    var fontName = item.name;
                    CKEDITOR.config.font_names = fontName +'/'+fontName + ';' + CKEDITOR.config.font_names;
                });
            },
            error : function() {
                displayError("Error while getting fonts.");
            },
        });
//  CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss ='../assets/invitations/fonts/fonts.css';

    CKEDITOR.config.font_names = 'Windsong/windsong;' + CKEDITOR.config.font_names;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also running into the same problem. You can create a css file at server side and write your css in that file. After this pass this file path to `CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = "Path/of/file"`